# Remove dot inside a number

Tags: json, vim, data-cleaning

I have the following JSON type file:

```
[{ "sid": "s-mtl-1", "MaterialNumber": "0.4440", "MaterialWNumber": "W0.4440", "tubePrice": "12"},
{ "sid": "s-mtl-2",  "MaterialNumber": "0.5550", "MaterialWNumber": "W0.5550", "tubePrice": "13"},
{ "sid": "s-mtl-3",  "MaterialNumber": "0.6660", "MaterialWNumber": "W0.6660", "tubePrice": "14"}]
```

And I would like to remove the dot in "MaterialWNumber" values, to have it like this:

```
[{ "sid": "s-mtl-1", "MaterialNumber": "0.4440", "MaterialWNumber": "W04440", "tubePrice": "12"},
{ "sid": "s-mtl-2",  "MaterialNumber": "0.5550", "MaterialWNumber": "W05550", "tubePrice": "13"},
{ "sid": "s-mtl-3",  "MaterialNumber": "0.6660", "MaterialWNumber": "W06660", "tubePrice": "14"}]
```

Anyone has an idea how to do this? I can't find a way to locate the value of "MaterialWNumber" and remove/change a character, which is inside a number/word to keep the original values.

Comment: `%s/\(W\d\+\)\.\(\d\+\)/\1\2`

Comment: thanks @svlasov. Works great in the VIM editor! Do you know by any chance how to do this in VIM extension for VS Code?

Comment: https://galenwong.github.io/blog/2021-03-22-vscode-neovim-vs-vscodevim/#search-and-replace

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: the code from @svlasov works good. In vscode neovim, the syntax is: ```%s/(W\d+).(\d+)/\1\2```(as mentioned in the link he provided)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler version.

```
:%s/\vW\d+\zs\.//g
```

doc:

- https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cv
- https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Czs

Answer (score 0):

As @svlasov commented, the task can be done in VIM editor as:
`%s/\(W\d\+\)\.\(\d\+\)/\1\2`.
Or in VS code neovim:
`%s/(W\d+).(\d+)/\1\2`.